# Visual Studio Update 2 - Task Runner Explorer - Project Open

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gulp, asp.net-core, task-runner-explorer

I'm trying to get a gulp watch task (to compile TypeScript files on save) to run with the ProjectOpened binding - but it just wont start when the project is opened.

It works fine if I start it manually in the Task Runner Explorer.

I'm using a ASP.NET Core Project (RC2), is there any nuget package or setting that must exist for the project opened gulp task to run?

Or a way to debug why it doesn't start?

---

**package.json:**

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "demo-website",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "3.9.1",
        "gulp-merge": "0.1.1",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "1.6.0",
        "gulp-typescript": "2.13.4",
        "jspm": "0.16.34",
        "typescript": "1.8.10",
        "typings": "^1.0.4"
    },
    "dependencies": { },
    "jspm": {
        "directories": {
            "baseURL": "wwwroot"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "bootstrap": "github:twbs/bootstrap@^3.3.6",
            "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@^0.1.21"
        },
        "devDependencies": { }
    }
}
```

---

**gulpfile.js:**

```
/// <binding BeforeBuild='ts-compile' ProjectOpened='watch-files' />

var gulp = require("gulp"),
    ts = require("gulp-typescript"),
    merge = require("gulp-merge"),
    sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");

var webroot = "./wwwroot/";

var paths = {
    tsSource: "./TypeScript/**/*.ts",
    tsOutput: webroot + "compiled/"
};

var tsConfig = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");

gulp.task("default", function () {
    // place code for your default task here
});

gulp.task("ts-compile", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.tsSource, "./typings/index.d.ts"])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts(tsConfig))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tsOutput));
});

gulp.task("watch-files", function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.tsSource, ["ts-compile"]);
});
```

Comment: Could you please share your `gulfile.js` and `package.json`?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a tooling bug with RC2 (Preview 1 of Tooling).  Looks like it will be fixed in Preview 2.

https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/516

Comment: Seems so, but if you open visual studio first and from within visual studio then open the project it seems to work.

Comment: Yep I'm seeing the same thing.  That's a decent workaround until it is fixed.